# checking apt-get update lock file

Tags: apt

I have in stalled a dual boot beside windows and now I'm having a problem checking `apt-get update` when I type in `apt-get update` this is the outcome. I don't know what to do

```
$ apt-get update  
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)  
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/  
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)  
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?  

$ apt-get upgrade  
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)  
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried putting `sudo` in front of your commands? Like this:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

This is necessary for every apt command, except for apt-cache.

The `sudo` command will temporarily set your rights to that of [root user](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superuser), which is necessary for certain programs.

Comment: yup this is the mistake

Comment: Also `cd apt-get update` doesn't make sense, unless you have a directory named `apt-get` in your current directory.

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal and run following commnads:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```